# Problem with Bevel modifier

Tags: modeling, bevel

I just started to learn Blender and met a problem when using Bevel modifier when creating a cogwheel. Most edges where processed fine, but a few of them got errors:

[image: Problem with Bevel modifier]

[image: Problem with Bevel modifier]

I have checked all the normals, they are correct. Here is the model without the modifier:

[image: Cogwheel model]

It seems ok, but I worry about black color of the edge exactly where the bevel makes mistakes

Comment: Removed doubles?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload the blend file so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to hint from `4-K`, I indeed found out that the problem was because of duplicates. To check it, I just moved single vertices in edit mode.

To remove them I did the following:

1. Open the edit mode for vertices.
2. Select all the vertices using `A` key.
3. Open special menu using `W` key.
4. Click "Remove Doubles".

Then Blender said that there were 8 redundant vertices, and I got correctly working bevel modifier.